# passing string pointers from class definition

Tags: c++, string

The problem i'm having is with the string parameter. I'm not exactly sure how to use it. I just want classification to have undefined length string from the onset until entered by user. The error i'm getting is **declaration of 'std::string classification' shadows a parameter** when i type string classification. What is the correct way to pass the string argument to class members?

> ---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


class Shapes 
{ //Begin Class Definition
      private:


       float side;
       float height;
       int exponent;
       string *classification;




      public:

             Shapes(float side, float height, string * classification);
             //CONSTRUCTOR
             ~Shapes(){};
             //DESTRUCTOR

      float area(float side, float height, string *classification);
      float perimeter(float side, float height, string *classification);




}; // End Class Definition



int power(float side, int exponent)

{
     int i;
     int total[exponent];
     float sum;

     for ( i = 0 ; i < exponent ; i ++ )
     {
      total[i]= side;
      sum *= total[i] ;

     }

     return sum;

}


float Shapes::area(float side, float height, string *classification)

{
     float area=0.0;
    string classification;
     getline(cin,string);

    if (classification == "square" ) 
    {

              area = power(side,2);
              return area;


    } 

      if (classification == "triangle" ) 
    {
         area = (side* height) / 2 ;
         return area;

    } 

      if (classification == "hexagon" ) 
    {
         float constant = 2.598706;

         area= constant * power(side,2);
         return area;

    } 


      if (classification == "circle" ) 
    {

    } 

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **redeclaring** the `string` named **classification**. You only have to declare that variable in the *class declaration* once for it to be used in all your member functions. You are also using the same name for your *arguments* which is confusing and dangerous.

You should also be careful what you are doing with **pointers** here, it seems like you're not exactly sure when to use them, or use **references**. If you indeed tried to compare your `string* classification` argument like this, `if (classification == "triangle" )`, you would realise that you can't compare **std::string* to const char***

Ideally, you should be using **enumerations** here, like so.

```
class Shape
{
  public:
    enum Classification { SQUARE, TRIANGLE, CIRCLE };
}

Shape::Area(float side, float height, Classification shapeClass)
{
  if(shapeClass == SQUARE) {} // Etc
}
```

Even ***better*** than that you would be using **inheritence** and **polymorphism** and overloading functions like `area()`

```
class Shape { virtual float Area(); };
class Triangle : public Shape { virtual float Area(); };
```

Comment: I like the enumeration way but my question is how do i call it in main. would it be like..  Shapes myshapes;  if (cin.getline()=="Square") myshapes(side,height, 1) ;

Comment: `myshapes(side,height, Shapes::Square);`

Comment: But as Luchian mentioned, this is really basic C++ stuff, and the way you're trying to do it is bad practice. You really need to learn about some of the concepts mentioned in the answers here, otherwise you're going to find your work confusing and painfully hard to manage.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `Shapes::area`, you don't need to redefine a variable `classification` typed `std::string`, because one of your parameters `string *classification` there.

You can use your parameter `*classification == "circle"`, the leading `*` is because you declare your parameter a pointer type. An alternatives is to declare `classification` as `string &classification` in C++, which is a reference. And with a reference parameter, you can use directly like `classificaiton == "circle"`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct way to pass the string argument to class members?

Don't. You already have access to the member inside the methods of a class, you don't need an extra variable, nor to pass it as a parameter.

```
float Shapes::area(float side, float height, string *classification)
{
    string classification;
```

In this case, you have **a parameter** called `classification`, **a member** with the same name, and **a local variable** with the same name.

Come to think of it, you don't even need pointers.

What you do need is to read a C++ book. I'm not being sarcastic nor mean. C++ is hard to get right, and you seem to have started working with pointers before you understand the even more basic concepts of variables or scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have the parameter name the same as the class member. They are not the same variable.

If you want to make the class member a shadow copy of the parameter, you should do:

```
float Shapes::area(float side, float height, string classification)
{
     float area=0.0;
     this->classification = classification;
     getline(cin,classification);

     //rest goes here
}
```

Here, `this` is a pointer to the holder class.

You will need to change the class declaration:

```
class Shapes
{
    string classification;
}
```

Do not use pointer to class unless really necessary. Use reference if you want to change the value.

P.S. Do not put semi colon in the end of function definition.

Comment: I did that but now i'm getting: invalid conversion from `std::string*' to `char'

Comment: @Undermine2k Sorry I accidentally put a `new` there. There should not be new because new is for memory allocation but `string()` already does that.

Comment: Just to let you know, `this->classification = string(classification);
` should be `this->classification = classification;` (its already a string) and `getline(cin,string);` should be `getline(cin,classification);` or some other string. However, it doesn't make sense to assign a string and then overwrite it on the next line though..

Comment: @JesseGood Yes you are right. Just realize that `string::operator=` already creates a duplicate.